# How to avoid explicitly specifying size for static array in class

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two classes A and B in C++11. There's a static array in class A, which is used in class B.
Here is the simplified problem:

```
// A.h
class A {
public:
    static int const a[4];
};

// A.cpp
int const A::a[4] = {1,2,3,4};

// B.h
class B {
public:
    void method();  
};

// B.cpp
void B::method() {
    for(auto const& it:a) {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

It works, but it requires the explicit definition of the array size. I would like to change the content of the array initializer from time to time, at compile time, without the manual redefinition of its size.

What would be an equivalent, but more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How about `std::vector`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there is a great difference between the two.

Comment: What do you mean? Change size of the array at **compilation** time or at runtime?

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, but if the OP wants to change the size at runtime, there's no other choice really.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, from the question it is not clear if size needs to be changed at runtime.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that the data of `a` may change in future builds, but for a given build, `a` will be constant. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I want to change its content only at compile time, otherwise it is constant. Its constant by its declaration.

Comment: Replace it with `std::array` or `std::vector` depending on your needs. I wonder why anybody would even use c-style arrays in 2017.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko `array` was my first guess, but then we can't define the object using its own `.size()` between the `[]`, or can we?

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko - Various reasons. And `std::array` is no better than a c-style array in this case. As for vector, it's overhead the OP doesn't want or need.

Comment: @underscore_d, since `std::array::size` is marked as `constexpr`, I don't see any issues with that.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko - You don't follow, the OP doesn't want to be forced into modifying the size parameter of the type in the class definition whenever they update the initializer for the array. With `std::array` they are **forced** to do so. Only with a `C-style` array can the size be omitted.

Comment: @VolodymyrLashko It does seem to work on a quick test, but then so does `decltype(Class::member) Class::member;` at the point of definition, so it seems `std::array` is not special here. Nor does it avoid having to specify the size at all, just avoids repeating it once, as StoryTeller said.

Comment: StoryTeller, underscore_d, yup, you're right. I have nothing more to add.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's `const` you can't do it. If it's `constexpr` however, you can:

```
class A {
public:
    static constexpr int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
};
```

Just move the initializer into the class definition. Then you can omit the array size completely.

---

A caveat to note, as pointed out by @SergeBallesta, is that you cannot skip on defining the storage for the array if you odr-use it. Which your example obviously does in the range for loop (it needs pointers to the beginning and past the end). So your cpp file still needs a `const int A::a[];` declaration.

In C++17 you can at least make the definition header only thanks to inline variables being added to the language.

Comment: It works only if the type of 'a' is a literal like 'int'. What if its type is 'std::string'?

Comment: @blzs - It works for any type which has a constexpr constructor. `std::string` doesn't, but it doesn't mean you can't define types that are.

Comment: Much better now :-)